# Is there any way to remove the stock ticker from Notification Center in iOS5?

Tags: notifications, ios

I like Notification Center in iOS5, but I find the stock ticker at the bottom a bit distracting. Is there any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Notifications > Stock Widget** and turn it **Off**.

*Notifications* for all apps that can display them are managed in *Settings*. Two built-in apps, Stocks and Weather, get exceptional treatment and show in Notification Center as widgets. In the Notifications Settings, they are listed as *Stock Widget* and the *Weather Widget*.

To prevent an app from displaying in Notification Center, click the app in the list and make sure the option “Notification Center” is set to off.

Comment: Ah! Thank you — I thought I’d looked through Settings but I ignored “Notifications” because it’s in the same place as “Push Notifications” was before, and I always ignored that because I never used them.